# Capturing the click event after the flipping of tile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I created zoom and flip of the tile.

So my tile having two different views. Initial view I am showing Image and back view I am showing the text.

So on click of the back side text I need to have an alert box. I tried having an alert and it is coming but multiple alerts are coming for me. Only the alert should come for the text not for the image side.

I am trying to add alert but it is not happening.

i need some support regarding this.

This is what I have tried.

HTML

```
<div class="wrap" id="html1"><div class="box"><div class="boxInner one clicked"><div class="face front"><img src="img/s.png"></div><div id="SearchDono" class="face back"><label class="text">Search Donors</label></div></div></div><div class="box"><div class="boxInner two two-clicked"><div class="face front"><img src="img/r.png"></div><div id="RegisterDono" class="face back"><label class="text">Register</label></div></div></div><div class="box"><div class="boxInner three three-clicked"><div class="face front"><img src="img/u.png"></div><div id="UpdateDetai" class="face back"><label class="text">Update Details</label></div></div></div><div class="box"><div class="boxInner one clicked"><div class="face front"><img src="img/s.png"></div><div class="face back"><div id="ShareStat" class="text">Share</div></div></div></div></div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
}

.box {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 25%;
    /* padding-bottom: 15%; */
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.boxInner {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.35, .6, 1.5);
    -o-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.35, .6, 1.5);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #666 0px 0px 6px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #666 0px 0px 6px;
    box-shadow: #666 0px 0px 6px;
}

.boxInner:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: #666 0px 0px 6px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #666 0px 0px 6px;
    box-shadow: #666 0px 0px 6px;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
    -o-transform: scale(1.05);
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

.boxInner img {
    width: 100%;
}

.front {
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1;
}

.back {
    -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
}

.face {
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
    position:relative;
}

.text{
    padding-top:35%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left:35%;
    color:#666666;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:100%;
}

.text::first-letter{
    font-size:400%;
    color:#009de0;
    margin-top:10px;
}


.box .one.clicked .back {
    opacity: 1;
}

.box .one.clicked .front {
    opacity: 0;
}

.box .one.clicked {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleY(-1);
}

.box .two.two-clicked .back {
    opacity: 1;
}

.box .two.two-clicked .front {
    opacity: 0;
}

.box .two.two-clicked {
     -webkit-animation: two-trans 3s;
     -moz-animation: two-trans 3s;
     -o-animation: two-trans 3s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes two-trans {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-200deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.box .two-clicked .back .text{
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    padding-bottom: 45%;
}


.box .three.three-clicked .back {
    opacity: 1;
}

.box .three.three-clicked .front {
    opacity: 0;
}

.box .three.three-clicked {
     -webkit-animation: three-trans 3s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes three-trans {
 0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(2000px);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
  }

  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.box .three-clicked .back .text{
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-2000deg);
    padding-bottom:45%;
}


body.no-touch .boxInner:hover .titleBox,body.touch .boxInner.touchFocus .titleBox
    {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
    /* Smartphone view: 1 tile */
    .box {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 650px) and (min-width : 481px) {
    /* Tablet view: 2 tiles */
    .box {
        width: 50%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 1050px) and (min-width : 651px) {
    /* Small desktop / ipad view: 3 tiles */
    .box {
        width: 33.3%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 1290px) and (min-width : 1051px) {
    /* Medium desktop: 4 tiles */
    .box {
        width: 25%;
    }
}
```

JS:

```
 $('.box').click(function(){
                $(this).addClass('hai');
            });
            $(".one").click(function(){
                $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
                $(this).addClass('backone');
                $('.backone').click(function(){alert('hai');
                $(this).removeClass('backone');
                });
            });
            $('.two').click(function() {
                $(this).toggleClass("two-clicked");
            });
            $('.three').click(function() {
                $(this).toggleClass("three-clicked");
            });
```

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/u22Mj/3/)

Comment: AddStyleClass ? its not jquery valid function. use addClass() function

Comment: Its not `$(this).addStyleClass('hai');` its `$(this).addClass('hai');`

Comment: @BharathRallapalli : hai bharath I tried with the alert, its coming but it should come for back view only.. If you click multiple times then its having issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple alerts are there beacause you have one click event inside another

Try changing the code to this

```
$(".one").click(function () {

    $(this).toggleClass("clicked");

    if ($(this).hasClass('backone')) {    //check if it already has class
        $(this).removeClass('backone');  //remove class

    } else {
        alert("hai");  //if not alert
        $(this).addClass('backone'); //addclass
    }
});
```

was not sure when you wanted to alert. So change the alert's position according to your requirement)

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/u22Mj/4/